# JRE Version Query

Tags: c#, java, .net

When i inspect the JRE version installed either through the command line using:

```
java -version
```

or through the the registry in the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment and the value CurrentVersion
```

i get 1.7.

However, when i query the registry value using C# as following:

```
string jreVersion = (string) Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment", "CurrentVersion", null);
```

It reads 1.5.

Can anybody help please?

P.S: I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 and .NET 4.0 and the JRE 1.7 is properly installed.

P.S: java -version reads:

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

The JavaSoft key contains the following subkeys:

1. Java Development Kit
2. Java Plug-in
3. **Java Runtime Environment**
4. Java Update
5. Java Web Start
6. Prefs

Comment: Are there any other subkeys installed under JavaSoft? Can you please provide the full output of java -version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running into registry redirection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx

On your machine do a manual check of the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
```

I am betting that value has 1.5 in it.

In C#, you can open the registry and specify if you want to use 64 or 32 bit using the OpenBaseKey method and specifying the RegistryView parameter:

```
RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
```